# The use of of repeated conjunction by tabloids

Tags: grammar, journalism

Here in Denmark, we have a tabloid newspaper (which will remain unnamed) which is infamous for, among other things, its ever-present writing mistakes, to the point that it almost seems intentional.

I recently became aware that certain American tabloid newspapers make exactly the same kind of writing mistake very often, namely repeating the conjunction in a sentence.

A good example would be the intentional mistake I included in the title of this question; "The use of of repeated conjunction by tabloids".

This got me thinking; Perhaps it is no mistake but actually intentional?

One reason I have been thinking that it might be intentional is that when I encounter a mistake like this one (repeated conjunction) I find myself reading the sentence two or three times before concluding that it must be a mistake, and also the fact that I get really annoyed by it tends to make the article stick in my memory.

So I was hoping that someone here could shed some light on this and perhaps confirm or dispute my suspicion, and in the case that I am right that it is intentional perhaps someone could point me to some academic papers on the subject.

Comment: I think this is is one of those things that most people don't notice unless they're looking for it.

Comment: “Of” isn’t a conjunction. It’s usually a mistake to repeat it twice ([see my related answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/387552/191178)). There are times it’s idiomatic that I can think **of of** course too though. (But I think this is more of a grammar question, which is off topic here.)

Comment: This sounds like an opinion-based question. I don't think you're likely to find research papers or any objective facts on this.

Answer (score 1):

One common reason for such 'mistakes' is to preserve a regular spacing between words in narrow justified columns.

Justification is the process by which the spacing between words is altered so that each row of text spans the width of the entire column. In narrow columns the spacing between words can vary significantly between rows.

Hyphenation and breaking longer words may be one way of reducing this effect. Doubling words that the brain skips over may be another.